# OverridePendingTransition(): How to modulate transition speed

Tags: android

I have a list view. I set an on click listener. If the user clicks on a list item, a new activity "slides" into view. The background activity remains static and fixed on screen.

How do I make the new activity `panel_slider` "slide faster"

`panel_slider.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="600"
        />
</set>
```

`main_activity_slider`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="700"
        />
</set>
```

`Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayPanel.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.main_activity_slide, R.anim.music_panel_slide);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:duration=` in `main_activity_slider`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="100"
        />
</set>
```

The durations are "reversed"